# Simplify a working function to replace specific words?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, truncate

I have a function to shorten certain words when the label wraps (to adjust to various resolutions). My function is working, but I think it can be simplified...just I'm not sure how. As I add more words here, the repetition can get out of hand fast. Could I put the long words/short words in an array and feed everything all at once or something? I couldn't get the fiddle working (even though it is working on my project), but here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/wucd1mws/1/ Thanks in advance!

```
if ($('label').height() > 20) {
    alert('Text wrapped');

    var numtext = $('label:contains("Number")')
    if (numtext) {
        numtext.each(function () {
            $(this).html($(this).text().replace('Number', '#'));
        });
    }

    var pertext = $('label:contains("Percent")')
    if (pertext) {
        pertext.each(function () {
            $(this).html($(this).text().replace('Percent', '%'));
        });
    }

    var invtext = $('label:contains("Invoice")')
    if (invtext) {
        invtext.each(function () {
            $(this).html($(this).text().replace('Invoice', 'Inv'));
        });
    }

    // etc...
}
```

I was thinking this is most likely the first step to shorten the function... now to feed in the long/short word pairs.

```
if ($('label').height() > 32) {
    var long = "Number";
    var short = "#";

    var labelwrap = $('label:contains('+ long +')')
    if (labelwrap) {
        labelwrap.each(function () {
            $(this).html($(this).text().replace(long, short));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you just say "*repetition*"?! I heard "loop"…

Comment: Well, you just edited the body of that loop into your question. Now you just need to iterate over a structure of `long`-`short` pairs (be it an array of arrays, or a simple key-value object)

Comment: fiddle doesn't work because your `if ($('label').height()...` will only test first label in page. Your other `if` 's as written will always be truthy even if elememts don't exist

Comment: How can I change this? Can you fix the fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much more optimal way in any means:

```
var short_trans = {
    'Percent': '%',
    'Number': '#',
    'Invoice': 'Inv',
    'Amount': 'Amt',
    'Shipping': 'Ship',
    'Production': 'Prod',
    'Allocated': 'Alloc',
    'Complete': 'Comp',
    'Manager': 'Mgr'
}

$('label').each(function(){
    if ($(this).height() > 20) 
    {
        var words = $(this).text().split(' '); 
        for (var i in words)
        {
            if (short_trans[words[i]])
            {
                words[i] = short_trans[words[i]];
            }
        }

        $(this).text(words.join(' '));
    } 
});
```

We once loop for any `label` tag, check if `height > 20`, then `split` text into words loop each word and check if shorten version exists, if so replace it

http://jsfiddle.net/wucd1mws/2/

Answer (score 3):

```
//objects can be used for hash lookups in javascript
var replaceValues = {
    'percent': '%',
    'number': '#'
    //etc.
}

var html = $('label').html(); //get the html of your element
for (var index in replaceValues) {
    if (html.indexOf(index) != -1) { //check if substring is present
        html.replace(index, replaceValues[index]); //if so replace with alt value
    }
}
```

Put this inside your initial conditional check.

EDIT: older browsers do not have `String.prototype.indexOf` and the replacement process as I wrote it is case-sensitive.

Comment: Can you edit your example above to feed more than one pair? How do the pairs not get mixed up? Percentage shouldn't end up as #.

Comment: They don't get mixed up because what he built works like a Dictionary object. It is a 1:1 relationship between key ('percent') and value ('%')

Comment: you can stuff any arbitrary number of comma-separated name-value pairs in that object, the loop will replace any occurence of the first with the second. So 'percent' becomes '%', 'number' becomes '#', etc. So the loop looks at all the object `index`es ('percent', 'number', etc, and replaces the string occurences with the object `replaceValues` at `index`. Google dictionary/hashtable/associative array to get a feel for the concept

Comment: with this approach you could replace wrong words in html. For example: 'This numbers is a percentage value' will be replaced with: 'This #s is a %age value'

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    truncateLabels("label");
});

function truncateLabels(element){
    var element_max_height = 20;
    var arr = [];
    arr[0] = ["Number", "#"];
    arr[1] = ["Percent", "%"];
    arr[2] = ["Invoice", "Inv"];

    if($(element).length){
        if($(element).height() > element_max_height){
            for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
                $(element + ':contains("' + arr[i][0] + '")').each(function(){
                    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(arr[i][0], arr[i][1], "gi"));
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This would work on all the browsers.

Also, I didn't understand why you're relying on the height of the element.

If you want to truncate a label, you can use the following library: [trunk8](http://jrvis.com/trunk8/)

```
$(".truncate").trunk8({lines:1});
$(".truncate2").trunk8({lines:2});
$(".truncate3").trunk8({lines:3});
```

Comment: I'm relying on the height because I only want to truncate if it wraps (so the height expands).Thanks for your solution, works nicely.

Comment: It's fine to use "Array()" to create a new array in JavaScript. I updated to the code. Now "Numbering" won't be replaced by "#ing". I'm using a RegExp to filter only the text that needs to be replaced. I've also added a flag to remove case-sensitivity.

Comment: @JaredSmith using `new Array()` or `[]` doesn't matter in this specific code. It's exactly the same because the variable won't be overwritten in this script. I cleaned/optimized the code of the OP and that's what matters. You really don't have to code the whole thing from scratch and push the OP to revamp his own script file. A simple question needs a simple answer.

Comment: Fair enough...I guess like a lot of us I get a little carried away with the code-golfish 'make this shorter' questions :)

Answer (score 2):

Short and sweet version using jQuery and an array of text items

```
var labelTextArr=[
    ['Number', '#'],
    ['Percent', '%'],
    ['Invoice', 'Inv']        
    ];
 var maxHt = 20

$.each(labelTextArr, function(i, arr){       
    $('label:contains('+arr[0]+')').html(function( _, html){       
        return $(this).height() > maxHt ? html.replace( arr[0], arr[1]) : html;
    });        
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hnx6bgag/2)**</kbd>

Comment: Can you modify this to only replace if the label wraps? I only want to replace when the text no longer fits the normal height.

Comment: I really like your short and sweet example, but I'm still catching some issues. See updated. http://jsfiddle.net/hnx6bgag/4/

Comment: use css to prevent wrapping